# Multiple file upload herror

Tags: php

I found a nice tutorial on YouTube by *Anthoniraj Amalanathan*. On the video tutorial, it works fine for hem but when I try to replicate it, I get an error. Here is the code:

```
<form action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <input type="file" name="upload[]">
    <input type="file" name="upload[]">
    <input type="submit" name="send" value="Send Now">
</form>

<?php

if(isset($_FILES['upload'])=== true)
{
    $files = $_FILES['upload'];
    for($x=0;$x<count($files['name']);$x++)
    {
        $name=$files['name'][$x];
        $tmp_name = $file['tmp_name'][$x];
        move_uploaded_file($files,'test/'.$name);
        echo 'Upload OK';
    }
}

?>
```

The message states that the error is on line 12 `($tmp_name = $file['tmp_name'][$x];)` but I don't seem to figure out why.

Can some one help here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, I tested it and it works for me.

```
<form action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
<input type="file" name="upload[]">
<input type="file" name="upload[]">
<input type="submit" name="send" value="Send Now">
</form>
<?php
if(isset($_FILES['upload'])=== true) {
    $files = $_FILES['upload'];
    for($x=0;$x<count($files['name']);$x++) {
        $name = $files['name'][$x];
        $tmp_name = $file['tmp_name'][$x];
        move_uploaded_file($files['tmp_name'][$x],'test/'.$name);
        echo 'Upload OK';
    }
}

?>
```

The error I got came from using an array as the temp. file location.  By changing it to $files['tmp_name'][$x], it worked.

Old: `move_uploaded_file($files,'test/'.$name);`

New: `move_uploaded_file($files['tmp_name'][$x],'test/'.$name);`

Comment: Whow, totally right... and also I found that the line above the move_upload is totally unnecessary.

Thanks for the help

Comment: You could actually use that variable, $tmp_name, instead if the $files['tmp_name'][$x] in the move code, if you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Its just a typo. `$file` is never declared, it should be `$files`.

Here:

```
$tmp_name = $file['tmp_name'][$x];
//               ^ missing s
```

Also here:

```
move_uploaded_file($files,'test/'.$name);
//                 ^^^^^^ shouldn't this be $tmp_name?
```

Comment: nice catch  I didnt even noticed, oh wait ... `$tmp_name` is never used!

Answer (score 0):

Try like this :

```
<?php 
if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'])){ 
    foreach($_FILES['upload']['name'] as $x=>$name) {
        $name = basename($_FILES['upload']['name'][$x}); 
        $folder = 'test/'; 
        $full_path = $folder.$name ;    
        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'][$x], $full_path)) { 
            echo 'Upload OK';
        } else { 
            echo 'Upload Failed'; 
        } 
    }
}else{ 
    echo 'Upload Not Received'; 
} 
?>
```